# Silverlight 4.0: How to increase quota in Isolated File Storage

Tags: silverlight-4.0, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

Got this line of code [here](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/17/tip-of-the-day-20-how-to-increase-the-isolated-storage-quota-for-your-app.aspx) but its not working.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            long newSpace = isf.Quota + 1523456786435;
            try
            {
                if (true == isf.IncreaseQuotaTo(newSpace))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("success");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("unsuccessful");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to remove all breakpoints and run it. I just copy the code from the article that you mentioned and it's working fine.

One more thing. if its not working then try with IE..

As you know, this code isf.IncreaseQuotaTo(newSpace) should be in user-initiated event. One  dialog will be shown to user and user need to agree on increasing the space.

Answer (score 3):

The request to increase the quota needs to come from a user-initiated event such as a key press or button click.

Refer to the remarks section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.increasequotato(VS.95).aspx

Comment: I already have a button and I place the above code in the click event.

Comment: This is just an utterly stupid restriction. I have written a caching mechanism that I now may have to scrap.

Why would they choose to limit it to user-events, you really are not gaining anything from this.

Comment: I agree, if you already have to ask for user permission using a dialog you can't touch, what's the point of this restriction?

Comment: One can only surmise that they have done it to prevent someone writing something malicious in SilverLight that swells Isolated Storage into GBs behind the scenes and then cause immense problems for the user. It'd be useful if, when you first ran a SilverLight app that it said up front the max space it was going to use and then set it once the user was happy with that and neither the coder nor the user would have to worry about it again. I can forsee this area changing quite a lot in future.

Answer (score 1):

Using breakpoints will invalidate the User Initiated action which Silverlight requires in order to increase the storage quota and will not increase the size when the call is made. Remove the breakpoints as advised and see if that solves your problem.

Using Debug.Writeline shouldn't cause a problem though. I tested my working code with them and it fired just fine.

My code is lifted from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265154(VS.95).aspx

The section I've taken is the IncreaseQuota_OnClick and referenced that from my button.

There's some other good methods in there too.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you remove all the breakpoints** before you execute your code. I was making the same mistake and as soon as I removed the breakpoints, the thing worked fine and I had managed to increase the size of IsolatedStorage successfully.

Comment: Where do you get the idea this user was making "the same mistake"?

Comment: Andrew, I'm assuming he was making the same mistake. I didn't see the need for you to ask this. I was facing similar problem and I did the same so I posted this as an answer.

Comment: Your assumption could cause someone to needlessly remove important breakpoints from their code, without even solving the issue. Assumptions make for bad answers.

Comment: I faced it and did it mate. It happened so with me as well and hence I put it here as and answer.